# ExtJS property grid not showing after afterrender listener

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a property grid I am creating an I have a listener on "afterrender" that looks something like this:

```
afterrender: function(){

                console.log(record);
                // im trying to get the record
                var gridValues = this.getSource();
                var store = this.getStore('teamMembers');
                store.clearFilter(true);
                store.addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                store.addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridValues.periodName});
                /*
                var store = this.getStore('teamMembers');
                store.clearFilter(true);
                store.addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                store.addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridvalues.periodName});
                */


                console.log(gridValues.resourcedFte);
                console.log(store.count());
                //this.getRecord();
```

My function is working correctly and doing what I want it to do for now, but after it has fired my property grids are not shown in my view. I have tried using doLayout() but that did not work.

Edit: the full code for my grid is:

```
var tempPropGrid = me.getView().add(
    {
        xtype:'propertygrid',
        width: 80,
        header: false,
        title: 'prop grid',
        //for some reason the headers are not hiding, we may need to deal with this using CSS
        //hideHeaders: true,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        sortableColumns: false,
        nameColumnWidth: 1,
        source: record.data,
        sourceConfig: {

            periodScrumMaster: {
                editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    store: team,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'personName',
                    valueField: 'personName',
                    listeners: {
'expand' : function(combo) {
                            var gridvalues = this.up('propertygrid').getSource();
                            combo.getStore().clearFilter(true);
                            combo.getStore().addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                            combo.getStore().addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridvalues.periodName});
                            var totalFTE = team.count();
                            console.log(totalFTE);
                        },
                    }}),
                displayName: 'Scrum Master'
            },
```

Comment: the code for your grid would help to solve the issue

Comment: Good point. have added it now. The grid works perfectly if I don't have the afterrender listener included.

Comment: This is strange. I don't thik you need to use the "afterrender" event for filtering the store, try to do it after the store is loaded and check if there is some errors in your console.